# Can the directory /sys have it's own partition?

Tags: partitioning, system

I just saw this question in a homework , and I just don't get it.
Is it possible for the directory /sys to have it's own partition.
Thanks!

Comment: Review your coursework: What is /sys? What does it do? What does it contain? Why is it there? When you understand /sys, you will know the answer to your question.

Comment: check what `/sys` is in the output of `mount | fgrep sys`

Comment: I know what is it and what it does contain ... any help ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question even means - the `/sys` directory is a mountpoint for the sysfs pseudo-filesystem *"which provides an interface to kernel data structures"* (see `man 5 sysfs`). Since the sysfs filesystem doesn't reside on a block device, the concept of partitioning doesn't really apply.

Comment: @steeldriver yeah, isn't that the answer? It makes no sense for `/sys` to have a partition as it's merely a mirage of the kernel